# Tier 4 bank statement requirements

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa, study, uk-visa

I would like to know the bank statement requirements for a U.K. study visa. Are they the same as a visit visa? Should the statement show stability and source?

Answer (score 2):

The financial documentation that has to accompany a Tier 4 student visa application is far greater than what is needed for a visit visa. You have to have all of the course fees for the first academic year and the living costs for each month of the course (up to a maximum of 9 months).  For example, if your fees are £12,000, and 9-months maintenance is £11,385 (£1,265.00 for each month), you would have to show a total of £23,385 in your account. Any deposit already paid to the university would be deducted from that amount and stated on your Confirmation of Acceptance for Studies (CAS) which is also submitted with the Tier 4 application.

Carefully review and follow the [UK Policy Guidance (pages 42 through 51)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/540421/T4_Migrant_Guidance_July_2016.pdf) on what financial statements are required.  Many Tier 4 visa refusals are because students do not have the required amount of money in their account or have not provided the correct evidence of the funds.

Comment: What about the source of money ? Should I provide evidence of the source of funds present in my bank account? Does the account need to be active with lots of transactions as in visit visa ?

Comment: Of course you do, and it has to be in the account, and stay there; otherwise, it's fund parking in an attempt to get a visa.  It has to be your account, joint with parents/guardian, gov't scholarship/grant etc. and you have to prove that it's yours or that you have a right to it. Revew the detailed instructions in the application for everything that has to be supplied.